# Offline map with capacitor, mapbox and mbtiles

Tags: ionic-framework, mapbox-gl-js, capacitor, mbtiles

i am trying to build an app working with offline map using mbtiles from openmaptiles and mapbox. i have followed this link : GitHub - oscarfonts/mapbox-gl-cordova-offline: Offline vector maps in Cordova using Mapbox GL JS and it was working fine with API 29 (cordova) but with API 30 (capacitor) i have this error :

ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: cordova-sqlite-ext plugin not available. Please install the plugin and make sure this code is run after onDeviceReady event

I have used `npm i cordova-sqlite-ext` but i still have the same error can anybody help
this is my ionic info

```
Ionic:

Ionic CLI : 6.17.1 (C:\Users\SAH\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules@ionic\cli)
Ionic Framework : @ionic/angular 5.9.1
@angular-devkit/build-angular : 12.1.4
@angular-devkit/schematics : 12.1.4
@angular/cli : 12.1.4
@ionic/angular-toolkit : 4.0.0

Capacitor:

Capacitor CLI : 3.3.2
@capacitor/android : 3.3.2
@capacitor/core : 3.3.2
@capacitor/ios : not installed

Utility:

cordova-res : 0.15.3
native-run : 1.5.0

System:

NodeJS : v14.17.6 (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe)
npm : 6.14.15
OS : Windows 10
```

Thanks

Comment: this repo seems not been modified for 3 years and at that time there was no sdk 30, so mostly the code has not been modified to work on sdk 29+ though not sure but seems its been un updated from a while....

Comment: I have the same problem now. Do you have a solution ? Please share. Thanks

Comment: seems no updates on the plugin till now, never tried this before but here is an angular implementation for it, `https://github.com/Wykks/ngx-mapbox-gl`.. but its still a web implementation and not native so perhaps could be a second solution..

Comment: still no updates on this? This does not mention anything about local offline tile hosting https://github.com/Wykks/ngx-mapbox-gl and the demo website is broken. Is doing this possible with capacitor? Maybe one should use the older cordova plugin to host the local server?